# How can I sort weighted items equally between containers?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I've recently been trying to devise an algorithm to sort an array of weighted items between *n* containers, such that the weighted sums of each container are as equal as possible.

After an hour or so, my current draft consists of ordering weighted values greatest to least, and sorting the greatest remaining value in the unsorted array into the container with the least sum value(if the least sum is equal with that of another column, the algorithm will choose randomly). The sorted value will be subsequently removed from the unsorted array.

At the moment, I'm refraining from coding this until I can consult some more experienced individuals regarding its accuracy. I have no formal CS training, but am familiar with a few algorithms. I initially looked at the solution to the knapsack problem, but found it difficult to translate given the fact that my example incorporates multiple containers.

Cursory tests of my earliest draft by manually applying it to a handful of values in a spreadsheet seem to indicate that it functions correctly.

With all of this in mind, please consider the following:

- [A] : Does the current draft function?
- [B] : Is it the most efficient version?
- [C] : If not, what is?

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

**SOLUTION: After asking on reddit, it became clear that this is just an implementation of the partition problem. To clarify, I incorrectly referred to partitions as containers prior to this point.**

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem correct in general if I understand your algorithm correctly. A counterexample would be two containers and items with weights 10, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3. The correct solution would be 10 + 5 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3.

As soon as your approach puts 10 and 5 in different containers it has lost since neither container can get to 15 by adding any of number of 3s and the the most equal distribution has 15 in each.

Comment: What would be a better implementation? The adding thing seems really reminiscent of the knapsack problem, but I can't figure out how to account for the multiple containers. Thanks for the response, BTW.

Comment: A slow but correct approach would be to test every possible assignment and record the one with the smallest difference between the heaviest and the lightest container.

It's possible that there is a dynamic programming approach to speed it up, but that requires some thought.